# Char/String comparison

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have a suggestion feature for the search function in my program eg I type janw doe in the search section and it will output NO MATCH - did you mean jane doe? I'm not sure what the problem is, maybe something to do with char/string comparison..I've tried comparing both variables as type char eg char temp -->temp.Contains ...etc but an error appears (char does not contain a definition for Contains). Would love any help on this! 8)

```
if (found == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nMATCH NOT FOUND");
            int charMatch = 0, charCount = 0;
            string[] checkArray = new string[26];
            //construction site  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            for (int controlLoop = 0; controlLoop < contPeople.Length; controlLoop++)
            {
                foreach (char i in userContChange)
                {
                    charCount = charCount + 1;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < userContChange.Length; )
                {
                    string temp = contPeople[controlLoop].name;
                    string check=Convert.ToString(userContChange[i]);
                    if (temp.Contains(check))
                    {
                        charMatch = charMatch + 1;
                    }
                }
                int half = charCount / 2;
                if (charMatch >= half)
                {
                    checkArray[controlLoop] = contPeople[controlLoop].name;
                }
            }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Console.WriteLine("Did you mean: ");
                for (int a = 0; a < checkArray.Length; a++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(checkArray[a]);
                }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what line of code are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 12):

A string is made up of many characters. A character is a primitive, likewise, it doesn't "contain" any other items. A string is basically an array of characters.

For comparing string and characters:

```
char a = 'A';
String alan = "Alan";
Debug.Assert(alan[0] == a);
```

Or if you have a single digit string.. I suppose

```
char a = 'A';
String alan = "A";
Debug.Assert(alan == a.ToString());
```

All of these asserts are true

But, the main reason I wanted to comment on your question, is to suggest an alternative approach for suggesting "Did you mean?". There's an algorithm called Levenshtein Distance which calculates the "number of single character edits" required to convert one string to another. It can be used as a measure of how close two strings are. You may want to look into how this algorithm works because it could help you.

Here's an applet that I found which demonstrates: [Approximate String Matching with k-differences](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/seqcomp/node3.html)

Also the wikipedia link [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: I'll have a look at the algorithm ;S looks complicated O_o. I'll let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: the algorithm is actually pretty simple, maybe see if you can find a better applet that shows you step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

Char type cannot have `.Contains()` because is only 1 char value type.

In your case (if i understand), maybe you need to use `.Equals()` or the `==` operator.

Note: for compare String correctly, use `.Equals()`,
the `==` operator does not work good in this case because `String` is reference type.

Hope this help!

Comment: You can compare two characters with the == operator. The key is that a String cannot be equal to a Character. One is basically an array of characters and other is a single letter,digit,etc.

Comment: Of course! i have noticed only the == operator on String comparing. The Char type can be compared with == operator, but it's a value type. Right?

Comment: Maybe I was not able to explain it clearly in the post, sorry!

Comment: Cant directly use == or Equals() to compare char and string, you still need to convert one of them. For example use: label[0].ToString().Equals("Z")

Comment: @Randel better `label[0] == 'Z'`

Answer (score 0):

`char` type dosen't have the `Contains()` method, but you can use iit like this: `'a'.ToString().Contains(...)`

if do not consider the performance, another simple way:

```
        var input = "janw doe";
        var people = new string[] { "abc", "123", "jane", "jane doe" };

        var found = Array.BinarySearch<string>(people, input);//or use FirstOrDefault(), FindIndex, search engine...
        if (found < 0)//not found
        {
            var i = input.ToArray();
            var target = "";

            //most similar
            //target = people.OrderByDescending(p => p.ToArray().Intersect(i).Count()).FirstOrDefault();

            //as you code:
            foreach (var p in people)
            {
                var count = p.ToArray().Intersect(i).Count();
                if (count > input.Length / 2)
                {
                    target = p;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(target))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(target);
            }
        }
```